# How to access Groups in Lotus Notes using C#

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, interop-domino

I am trying to access Groups from Lotus Notes using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notes / Domino, Groups are stored as notes documents within the Name and Address Book (NAB) database, which is generally stored as names.nsf in the home data folder of the server. If you are trying to access details of a group (say, the group's membership list), you can do this in the same way that you would access documents in any Notes database. So, from C#, you can use the domino.dll API. I don't have sample code, but the basic steps would be:

- get a handle to a Session
- from the Session object, get a handle to the NAB database using GetDatabase
- from the database, get a handle to the view which holds group documents, using the GetView method. The view name is "Groups".
- from the view, you can look up a particular group document (using the GetDocumentByKey method) or yo9u can walk all documents in the view (using GetFirstDocument() and GetNextDocument()
- with a handle to a document, you can use the GetItemValue and GetFirstItem, etc methods to get at the list of members, the group title, description, etc. attributes.